# Can't connect to SQL server (net::err_connection_refused)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, reactjs, firebase

When I try to click on the Register button and connect to the server I get this error, my firebase gets the username and password just fine but my SQL Server is unable to do so because the code fails to connect:

```
import React from 'react';
    import firebase from '../firebase-config.js';
    import { Button, ButtonGroup, Input, InputLabel } from '@material-ui/core';
    import '../css stylesheets/LoginComponent.css';
    import { post } from '../Calls';
    import {userRoute} from '../ApiRoutes';
    class Register extends React.Component {
    
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
    
            this.state = {
                User: {
                    password: '',
                    email: ''
                }
            }
            this.handleChange = (e) => {
                let newUser = this.state.User;        
                newUser[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
                this.setState({User: newUser});
            }
            this.register = async () => {
                
                firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.User.email, this.state.User.password).then();
                const newUser = {
                    Email: this.state.User.email,
                    Password: this.state.User.password,
                    RolId:2
                }
```

This is where I'm trying to connect to my SQL server in backend:

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import db from './dbConfig.js';
import Rol from './models/Rol.js';
import Utilizator from './models/User.js';
import Activitate from './models/Activitate.js';
import user from './routes/UserRoutes.js';
import rol from './routes/RolRoutes.js';
import feedback from './routes/FeedbackRoutes.js';
import Feedback from './models/Feedback.js';
import activity from './routes/ActivitateRoutes.js'
let app = express();
let router = express.Router();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/api',rol);
app.use('/api',user);
app.use('/api',feedback);
app.use('/api',activity);

// Autentificare la baza de date
db.authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
  });
//Relatie One to Many Rol si Utilizator
Rol.hasMany(Utilizator, { as: "Users", foreignKey: "RolId" });
Utilizator.belongsTo(Rol, { foreignKey: "RolId" });


//Activitati
Utilizator.hasMany(Activitate, { as: "Activitati", foreignKey: "UserId" });
Activitate.belongsTo(Utilizator, { foreignKey: "UserId" });

//Feedback
Utilizator.hasMany(Feedback, { as: "Feedback", foreignKey: "UserId" });
Feedback.belongsTo(Utilizator, { foreignKey: "UserId" });


let port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port);
console.log('API is runnning at ' + port);
```

Could someone please tell me how I should fix this?

Comment: I don't see any backend code that might be connecting to a sql server. It's likely that your connection info is incorrect. Try verifying the info via sam's or another external tool.

Comment: @Deadron Hello! I've just updated my code. What tool can I use if there's still no solution?

Comment: You can use SSMS or any number of available db clients.

Comment: Ah yes, I am using SSMS and when I'm testing it with Postman it works out fine, the issue that I'm getting and cannot figure out is when I'm trying to save what I'm using in React into my db.

Comment: If Postman is working then what makes you think your sql server connection is failing?

Comment: If API testing (Postman) indicates that it is working, then either your front end is connecting to a different instance of your API (configuration issues) or your front end is not able to connect to the API at all, config is your likely area to solve this.